# Laravel 5 Footer How to Avoid creating a lot of templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating an app in Laravel 5, with a footer that's going to have alot of links with sections. The idea is that, when I click on a footer link of a section, it's going to redirect me to a template page, where on the left, are all the links in that footer, and on the right, the content of the link I clicked.

For example, on this picture, I click on Link A in the footer, and it shows all the links from Section 1(with Link A underlined) on the left, and on the right it shows the content of Link A. [image]

Basically I want to know if there is a good way to do this without creating 50 different templates(one for each link of the footer).

Comment: Show what you tried so far.Its not a site where you get develop your project.Show your code then SO coder try to solve a specific issue.

Comment: That's the thing, the only way I can think of is to create a template for each of the footer links. That's easy, but I was wondering if there is a "better" way of doing this without creating 50 templates(one for each footer link)

Comment: You can do it with partial blade and then you can dynamic the content in partial view.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using just 3 templates:

main.blade.php:

```
<html>
<body>
@include('sidebar')
..
@yield('content')
..
@include('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

sidebar.blade.php

```
<div class="sidebar">
@foreach($sidebar_links as $link)
   // print $link
@endforeach 
</div>
```

footer.blade.php

```
<div class="footer">
<a href="{{ route('getMenu', 'section A') }}">Section A</a>
<a href="{{ route('getMenu', 'section B') }}">Section B</a>
</div>
```

Controller action:

```
public function getMenu($section) {
  $sidebar_links = // Get sidebar links of the section which is clicked from the bottom links
   return ('main', compact('sidebar_links'))
}
```

Note: I have not tested this, but it should give you the basic view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request::segment() for finding the active link. For example the link of Link A = /link/a then we can say Request::segment(2) == a. You can you use that to show what is the active link.

```
<a href="/link/a" class="@if(Request::segment(2) == 'a') active @endif">Link A</a>
<a href="/link/b" class="@if(Request::segment(2) == 'b') active @endif">Link B</a>
<a href="/link/c" class="@if(Request::segment(2) == 'c') active @endif">Link C</a>
```